# "SyntaxError: super() is only valid in derived class constructors"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Не могу понять в чем проблема, подскажите пожалуйста

И еще, может ли кто-нибудь объяснить зачем нужно `super`? Зачем туда передаются аргументы?

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(name, voice) {
    this.name = name;
    this.voice = voice;
  }
  
  say() {
    console.log(`${this.name} said ${this.voice}`);
  }
}

class Bird extends Animal {
  сonstructor(name, voice, canFly) {
    super(name, voice);
    this.canFly  = canFly;
  }
}

const duck = new Bird('Dick', 'Crack');

duck.say();
duck.say();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В коде в вопросе, в классе Bird опечатка, первая буква `c` - не английская, что делает описанный метод, не конструктором, а обычным методом.

Если исправить - то ошибка использования `super` уйдет.

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(name, voice) {
    this.name = name;
    this.voice = voice;
  }
  
  say() {
    console.log(`${this.name} said ${this.voice}`);
  }
}

class Bird extends Animal {
  constructor(name, voice, canFly) {
    super(name, voice);
    this.canFly  = canFly;
  }
}

const duck = new Bird('Dick', 'Crack');

duck.say();
duck.say();
```

Для чего в этом случае нужно `super`?

Для того, чтобы можно было вызвать конструктор базового класса, и проинициализировать все необходимые поля.

Если его не вызывать, то на уровне языка решено было запретить обращаться к `this`, который указывает на создаваемый объект, так как он может быть не инициализированным.

---

Еще одним примером использования ключевого слова `super` может являться обращение к полям и методам базового класса, например:

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(name, voice) {
    this.name = name;
    this.voice = voice;
  }

  say() {
    console.log(`${this.name} said ${this.voice}`);
  }
}

class Bird extends Animal {
  constructor(name, voice, canFly) {
    super(name, voice);
    this.canFly = canFly;
  }
  say() {
    console.log('Bird say');
    super.say();
  }
}

const duck = new Bird('Dick', 'Crack');

duck.say();
duck.say();
```

Подробнее о `super` можно посмотреть [в справке](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super).

Comment: Хотелось бы еще узнать, что такое поля?

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi, например то, что ты  в конструкторе через this присваиваешь: `this.voice = voice;`, `this.canFly = canFly;` и т.д.